# How to return the name of dataframe column in an array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to iterate my code, and created a list full with 4 dataframe columns. Is there a way to return the dataframe column name in the array?

code:

```
df1['c1'] = df1['c1'].apply(lambda x: 'test')
df1['c2'] = df1['c2'].apply(lambda x: 'test')
df2['c1'] = df2['c1'].apply(lambda x: 'test')
df2['c2'] = df2['c2'].apply(lambda x: 'test')
```

What I tried:

```
tables = [df1['c1'], [df1['c2'], df2['c1'], df2['c2']]

for i in tables:
  i = i.apply(lambda x: 'test')
```

Essentially: how to call the items in tables list, and return the actual value, not the table itself.

Desired:

```
tables = [df1['c1'], [df1['c2'], df2['c1'], df2['c2']]

for i in tables:
  # iterates by calling the name of each dataframe column in tables so it 

Essentially how to call the items in tables list, and return the dataframe variable name.... 
so it returns:

[df1['c1'], [df1['c2'], instead of the actual dataframe.
```

Comment: do you need `df1.columns.tolist()`?

Comment: no, I already have the name in my tables variable

Comment: what are you trying to do here? could you show with an example exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: I updated the original post

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what's going on here. Could you show it with a df?

Comment: Do you want to maintain df1, df2 separately? You could also combine the 2 with this code and then use applymap `df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)  
df3 = df3.applymap(lambda x: 'test')`

Comment: @Mick, As i see you have some df columns in tables not the column names.

Comment: @keramat excatly, i want to return the df column names in tables, not the actual df column dataframe

Comment: not sure IIUC, but if you just want to return the column names in tables, you can simply use `[t.name for t in tables]` which will return `['c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2']` (I guess the bracket before the second item in `tables` is just a typo, isn't it)

Comment: @Stef this is exactly what i'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Mick you also you can use [x for x in df.columns]